# Python - How to turn strings into PNGs of the text

Tags: python, string, png, thumbnails

I am building a thumbnail creation program and I need to turn a string into an image of that string so that it can be pasted into the thumbnail. I am using the PIL Image module for working with my images.

For example, if I am given a string of "#53" I want to be able to create a PNG of that string so that I can put it in the bottom right corner of the thumbnail. My current plan for implementing this is to have a PNG of every single character in a folder, and then loop through the string and stitch together the images of the single characters until the whole string is stitched together. However, this seems a little sloppy, and it would also be hard to change fonts and it would also be difficult to even find such a library of PNGs for every single letter. Any suggestions?

Comment: Using PIL, you can write the string onto the text, and save the result as a PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIL does what you want directly. From the docs, http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagefont.htm

```
import ImageFont, ImageDraw

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# use a bitmap font
font = ImageFont.load("arial.pil")

draw.text((10, 10), "hello", font=font)

# use a truetype font
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 15)

draw.text((10, 25), "world", font=font)
```

Comment: How does ImageDraw find the font that I want? The program is throwing an error right now because it cannot find the font. I put it inside the folder that the program is stored in, I am also using a .otf is that what is causing an error? Thanks

Comment: How to set up fonts is described in the docs (pillow docs might be more updated: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/ImageFont.html)